# Getting containers to run with a Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am having trouble with writing making `Jenkinsfile`.
My environment:

- A server running docker
- Jenkins is running as a container on the server

I have a Docker image on DockerHub, and I have no problem fetching that image.

My `Jenkinsfile` currently looks like this:

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'emil2709/servopsdockerfile'
      args '-d -p 80:80 /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage ('Testing') {
      steps {
        sh 'echo testing'
      }
    }
    stage ('Deploying') {
      steps {
        sh 'echo deploying'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The container won't run.
I want to:

- Make a test-container
- If all my tests are ok, I want to deploy a new container witch is the webserver.

My issue is getting a Docker container to run, how can i do this?

Comment: does the machine where jenkins runs have the docker daemon?

Comment: Yes the machine has the docker daemon.

Comment: do you have Dockerfile ready?

Comment: Yes i do. My dockerfile is an ubuntu 14.04 running apache.

Answer (score 4):

You can run your test on a docker image which has necessary tools to build and test your source code. Then, after building the project, you can create a new docker image.

Let's say you have a java project using maven. In this scenario, test and build your source code. Then, in the next stage, just create your docker image.

IMAGE_ID: the docker image including necessary tools, in the example, maven.

And you need a Dockerfile to issue the command `docker build`

```
pipeline {

  stages {
    stage ('Building') {
      steps {
        sh '''
        docker run -i --rm -v ./:/src -w /src IMAGE_ID  /bin/bash -c "mvn test package" 
        '''
      }
    }
    stage ('dockerization') {
      steps {
        sh '''
        docker build -t your_tag .
        docker push ...
        '''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A minimal Dockerfil example:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
COPY target/*.jar /app/application.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /app/application.jar
```